# Conditional Node In Formkit Repeater

Tags: vuejs3, formkit

I am trying to do a conditional render of a datepicker in a formkit repeater. It's unclear to me how I am supposed to get the node on the child.

The `$index` should be avaliable to all childern of the reaperter per the [docs](https://formkit.com/inputs/repeater#schema-example). Thanks for your help!

See [playground](https://formkit.com/playground?fkv=latest&fileTab=Playground.vue&files=jc%5B%28%27L%21%27Playground.vue%27%7Eeditor%21%27%3CscripXsetup6O9SBI%40fYkit%2Fvue1ZOqf%2C+computedIvue17sBA%5B_%28_53qpeGr4_L3users4_U8%5B*%28*253text4*2L3ez2%2F%2F+T+is+available+to+U.*2label3Ez%29R%28*581checkbox1RL81hasDG1Rlabel81Has+dG%3F1%2C_%29R%28*53dGpicker4*L3dG4*if3%24users%5BT%5D.%24hadDG%22*%29_%5D%2C0%290%5D7MAqf%7B%7D7WA%7B%7Dw%3E+alert%7B1Valid+sN%27%3A1%7DZ0Cscript60%3Cj%3C9+typeJfYQv-modelJMQ%40sNJW162%3C9SB+%3AsBJsBQ%3AMJMQ%2F6C960%3Cpq6%28%28+M+%29%290Cpq6Cj%27%7Eadded%21true%29%5D*_20%5Cn1%5C%272++38%224%22%2C5%24fYkit6%3E07Z0consX8%3A+9FYKitAw+BchemaC%3C%2FGateI+%29+from+1J%3D1LnameMdataNubmitOimporX%28+Q1+R%2C*T%24indexUchildqnWhandleSNXt+YormZ%3B0_02jtemplG6qrew+%3Dzmail4*%01zwqj_ZYXWUTRQONMLJIGCBA9876543210*_&imports=jc%28%27name%21%27ImpRtMap%27%7EeditR%21%27%28EDK59TDBK5B%400.8.4OB.Qm.js6D2D7%3FD%3D596cRe2cRe*G2G*dev2dev*themQ2themQ*i18n2i18n*inputs2inputs*N2N*rulQ2rulQ*G2G*J2J7HP%29P%27%29*762KCL.iF5Cjsdelivr.neFnpm%2FD6T%40LiF7%40%25LitVSsionInject%259%403O.Qm-browsS.jsA+HB3-sfc-loadSChttps%3A%2F%2Fcdn.DvueEP+AFt%2FGutilsH%5C%27JvalidationK%5C%21ALfRmkNobsSvSO%2FdisFDP%5CnQesRorSerTH%2CE%01TSRQPONLKJHGFEDCBA97652*_&css-framework=genesis)

```js
<script setup>
import { FormKitSchema } from "@formkit/vue";
import { ref, computed } from "vue";

const schema = [
  {
  $formkit: 'repeater',
  name: 'users',
  children: [
    {
      $formkit: 'text',
      name: 'email',
      // $index is available to children.
      label: 'Email',
    },
    {
    $formkit: "checkbox",
    name: "hasDate",
    label: "Has date?",
  },
    {
    $formkit: 'datepicker',
    name: 'date',
    if: '$users[$index].$hadDate'
    }
  ],
}
];

const data = ref();

const handleSubmit = () => alert("Valid submit!");

</script>

<template>
<FormKit type="form" v-model="data" @submit="handleSubmit">
  <FormKitSchema :schema="schema" :data="data" />
</FormKit>

<pre>
{{ data }}
</pre>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$value` to get the current element's value. In your case, the correct value of the datepicker subfield `if` is: `'$value.hasDate'`.

[Updated playground](https://formkit.com/playground?fkv=latest&fileTab=Playground.vue&files=jc%5B%28%27name%21%27Playground.vue%27%7Eeditor%21%27%3CscripXsetup6N8SBJ%40fYkit%2Fvue1ZNU%2C+computedJvue15sBA%5B0*%2804repe7r12Gusers12children3%5BIztext9*GeRTER9%292zcheckbox9*GMTHas+d7%3F9%292zd7picker9*Gd79*if31%24value.M9%292%5DO*%29O%5D5qAU%7B%280*users3%5BI%28I*eR31a%40b.c9M3false2%292%28I*eR3null2*M3true2%29O*%5DO%29%7D5WA%7B%7D+%3D%3E+alert%7B1Valid+sL%27%3A1%7DZCscript60%3Cw_8+typeQfYjv-modelQqj%40sLQW16*_8SB+%3AsBQsBj%2F6*C860_pre%3E%28%28+q+%29%29Cpre6Cw0%27%7Eadded%21true%29%5D*++0%5Cn1%5C%272%2CI3%3A+4**%24fYkit315Z0consX6%3E07ate8FYKit912*A+%3D+BchemaC%3C%2FGname31I0**J+%29+from+1LubmitMhasD7NimporX%28+O%2C0Q%3D1RmailT9*label31UreactiveWhandleSLXt+YormZ%3B0_*%3Cj1+qdatawtempl76z*%28I4%01zwqj_ZYXWUTRQONMLJIGCBA9876543210*_&imports=jc%28%27name%21%27ImpRtMap%27%7EeditR%21%27%28EDK59TDBK5B%400.8.4OB.Qm.js6D2D7%3FD%3D596cRe2cRe*G2G*dev2dev*themQ2themQ*i18n2i18n*inputs2inputs*N2N*rulQ2rulQ*G2G*J2J7HP%29P%27%29*762KCL.iF5Cjsdelivr.neFnpm%2FD6T%40LiF7%40%25LitVSsionInject%259%403O.Qm-browsS.jsA+HB3-sfc-loadSChttps%3A%2F%2Fcdn.DvueEP+AFt%2FGutilsH%5C%27JvalidationK%5C%21ALfRmkNobsSvSO%2FdisFDP%5CnQesRorSerTH%2CE%01TSRQPONLKJHGFEDCBA97652*_&css-framework=genesis).